# awk to add text to each pattern in field

Tags: awk

In the below `awk` I am trying to add `:p.=` to each `$7` only if they have the pattern `/NM/` in it.  The below seems to do that if there is only one `NM` in `$7`, like line 2. However if there are multiple `NM` in `$7`, like line 3 then the `:p.=` gets added only to the last. A `;` is used to separate multiple `NM` in the field. I added comments, but am not sure what I am not doing, thats needed. Thank you :).

**input** `tab-delimited`

```
R_Index Chr Start   End Ref Alt Detail.refGene  Gene.refGene
1   chr1    948846  948846  -   A   dist=1  ISG15
2   chr1    948870  948870  C   G   NM_005101:c.-84C>G  ISG15
3   chr1    948921  948921  T   C   NM_005101:c.-33T>C;NM_005101:c.-84C>G   ISG15
4   chr1    949654  949654  A   G   .   ISG15
```

**awk**

```
awk '
  BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }  # define FS and OFS as tab and start processing
  $7 ~ /NM/ {            # look for pattern NM in $7
       # split $7 by ";" and cycle through them
          i=split($7,NM,";")
             for (n=1; n<=i; n++) {
              sub("$", ":p=", $7)   # add :p. to end off each $7 before the ;
    }     # close block
}1' input  # define input file
```

**current output** `tab-delimited`

```
R_Index Chr Start   End Ref Alt Detail.refGene  Gene.refGene
1   chr1    948846  948846  -   A   dist=1  ISG15
2   chr1    948870  948870  C   G   NM_005101:c.-84C>G:p.=  ISG15
3   chr1    948921  948921  T   C   NM_005101:c.-33T>C;NM_005101:c.-84C>G:p.=p.=    ISG15
4   chr1    949654  949654  A   G   .   ISG15
```

**desired output** `tab-delimited`

```
R_Index Chr Start   End Ref Alt Detail.refGene  Gene.refGene
1   chr1    948846  948846  -   A   dist=1  ISG15
2   chr1    948870  948870  C   G   NM_005101:c.-84C>G:p.=  ISG15
3   chr1    948921  948921  T   C   NM_005101:c.-33T>C:p.=;NM_005101:c.-84C>G:p.=   ISG15
4   chr1    949654  949654  A   G   .   ISG15
```

Comment: who comes up with these horrible formats?  It's neither machine nor human friendly.

Comment: Sorry, I tried indenting the code to be more readable but unfortunately the file types come like this from the instrument.... I guess maybe I should view it in excel maybe that will help.  Thank you :).

Comment: `:p.=` drooling on tie? :D

Comment: that is too funny :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this:

```
      i=split($7,NM,";")
         for (n=1; n<=i; n++) {
          sub("$", ":p=", $7)   # add :p. to end off each $7 before the ;
         }
```

with this:

```
      out=""
      i=split($7,NM,/;/)
         for (n=1; n<=i; n++) {
          sub(/$/, ":p=", NM[i])   # add :p. to end off each NM[i] before the ;
          out = (out=="" ? "" : out";") NM[i]
         }
      $7 = out
```